# SSH server Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

In the past I set up an ssh server with pubkey-only authentication on a kali linux, and it worked, but now I am on Ubuntu 18.10 and it won't work. When I try to connect with client I get: `Permission denied (publickey)`

Usually, on kali, I'd use ssh tunneling service serveo.net with the following command successfuly:

`ssh -R crayyhost:22:localhost:1337 serveo.net`

And I'd connect to the server like this: `ssh -J serveo.net auser@crayyhost`

But here I simply can't. I cant connect to myself... The server is on ubuntu and the client is on kali.

I can't even connect with `ssh auser@EXTERNAL_IP -p 1337` - I get "Connection refused".

The same goes for LAN: `ssh auser@192.168.1.2 -p 1337` - "Permission denied"

The server can connect to himself with `ssh localhost -p 1337`, and the server can even connect to himself remotely with `ssh -J serveo.net auser@crayyhost`, but the client can't.

The client's `id_rsa.pub` file has been added to `.ssh/authorized_keys`

I even disabled `StrictMode` in `sshd_config`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Connection refused" means there's probably a firewall in the way. Try running `telnet 1337` to verify that the port is at least accessible from where you're trying to connect.

"Permission denied" for `ssh auser@192.168.1.2 -p 1337` suggests that, besides a firewall, your public key isn't properly installed. if you have added the .pub key to the correct directory, maybe try restarting the ssh service to make sure it picks it up.

other than that, double check everything that's listed in the answer to this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/46424/how-do-i-add-ssh-keys-to-authorized-keys-file

Comment: Weird. I re-created the client rsa key 3 times by now and re-added it and it wouldn't work. I'd restart ssh every time. Now I added a pubkey to authorized_keys without deleting the old one and it worked. (Now there's 1 current and 1 outdated rsa key of that client)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify your private key.

Use `ssh -i <private key path> user@server -p 1337`

For example if you are in the directory with your private key thats copied directly to your machine, you could use `ssh -i id_rsa auser@192.168.1.XX -p 1337`. This tells it to use a private key that you have specified.

You could also research on how to add this to the config file in ~/.ssh to automate it, as well as the port.